# Hazelcast cache database data cache java

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

this class implements MapStore

```
package jdbc;
import com.hazelcast.core.MapStore;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.lang.String.format;
import data.Person;

public class PersonMap implements MapStore<Long, Person> {

    private final Connection con;
    private PreparedStatement allKeysStatement;

    public PersonMap() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "hr", "hr");
           /* con.createStatement().executeUpdate(
                    "create table if not exists person (id bigint not null, name varchar(45), primary key (id))");*/
            allKeysStatement = con.prepareStatement("select * from person");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void delete(Long key) {
        System.out.println("Delete:" + key);
        try {
            con.createStatement().executeUpdate(
                    format("delete from person where id = %s", key));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void store(Long key, Person value) {
        try {
            con.createStatement().executeUpdate(
                    format("insert into person values(%s,'%s')", key, value.name));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void storeAll(Map<Long, Person> map) {
        for (Map.Entry<Long, Person> entry : map.entrySet())
            store(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    public synchronized void deleteAll(Collection<Long> keys) {
        for (Long key : keys) delete(key);
    }

    public synchronized Person load(Long key) {
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = con.createStatement().executeQuery(
                    format("select name from person where id =%s", key));
            try {
                if (!resultSet.next()) return null;
                String name = resultSet.getString(1);
                return new Person(key, name);
            } finally {
                resultSet.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public synchronized Map<Long, Person> loadAll(Collection<Long> keys) {
        Map<Long, Person> result = new HashMap<Long, Person>();
        for (Long key : keys) result.put(key, load(key));
        return result;
    }

    public Iterable<Long> loadAllKeys() {
        return new StatementIterable<Long>(allKeysStatement);
    }

}
```

this is person class
package data;
import java.io.Serializable;

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    public Long id;
    public String name;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person{name='" + name + "'}";
    }
}
```

this main method class but i cant load the data in instance.

```
import com.hazelcast.core.*;
import com.hazelcast.config.*;
import com.hazelcast.config.MapStoreConfig.InitialLoadMode;

import data.Person;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

import jdbc.PersonMap;

public class GettingStarted {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
       /* Config cfg = new Config();
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
        Map<Integer, String> mapCustomers = instance.getMap("customers");
        mapCustomers.put(1, "Joe");
        mapCustomers.put(2, "Ali");
        mapCustomers.put(3, "Avi");
        HazelcastInstance instance1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
        Map<Integer, String> mapCustomers1 = instance.getMap("customers");
        mapCustomers1.get(1);

        System.out.println("Customer with key 1: "+ mapCustomers1.get(1));
        System.out.println("Map Size:" + mapCustomers1.size());

        Queue<String> queueCustomers = instance.getQueue("customers");
        queueCustomers.offer("Tom");
        queueCustomers.offer("Mary");
        queueCustomers.offer("Jane");
        System.out.println("First customer: " + queueCustomers.poll());
        System.out.println("Second customer: "+ queueCustomers.peek());
        System.out.println("Queue size: " + queueCustomers.size());*/
        Config config = new Config();
         PersonMap simpleStore = new PersonMap();
      //  XmlConfigBuilder configBuilder = new XmlConfigBuilder();
       // Config config = configBuilder.build();
        MapConfig mapConfig = config.getMapConfig("personMap");

        MapStoreConfig mapStoreConfig = new MapStoreConfig();
        mapStoreConfig.setImplementation(simpleStore);
        mapStoreConfig.setWriteDelaySeconds(0);
        mapStoreConfig.setInitialLoadMode(InitialLoadMode.EAGER);
        mapConfig.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreConfig);
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
        IMap<Long, Person> personMap = hz.getMap("personMap");
        System.out.println(personMap);
        Person p = personMap.get(1);
        System.out.println(p);

    }
}
```

please help me to load data..its  returning null
i tryed to run it with two nodes..but database data not coming..
can database insert reflect in map synchronizely

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance, your configuration of HZ seems to be fine.

A few questions:

```
allKeysStatement = con.prepareStatement("select * from person");
```

You are loading the whole person here, instead of the keys. Afaik your query should be something like 'select id from person'

Also add some logging statements to your PersonMap (please rename it to PersonMapStore to prevent name confusion. Your PersonMap is not a map). This way you can see which calls are being done. Especially the call to loadAllKeys and loadAll are important to get logged. Once you have added the logging can you update your post so we can see what is going on.